# PHP: Check with a tail of string is contains number after 'dash'

Tags: php

How can I rip off of below string if contains -12345 at tail?

```
'product name with color-0250'      -> 'product name with color'
'product name with size-300'        -> 'product name with size'
'product name with something-11200' -> 'product name with something'
```

What I wants is only the name of the product.

Comment: Can you explain it little more?

Comment: It would be probably sufficient to test `substr($s, 0, 6) == '-12345'` ... is it that what you though of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `explode()` and explode by '-' presuming the product name will never contains a '-'.

```
$strProductName = 'product name with color-0250';
$arrParts = explode('-',$strProductName);
echo $arrParts[0]; // Returns: product name with color
```

You could also use a regular expresion with preg_match or preg_replace. Using preg replace you can capture the product name even if it contains '-'

```
echo preg_replace('/(\-[0-9]+)$/i', '', 'product name with color-0250');
// Returns: product name with color
```

Answer (score 2):

Another variant with `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace("/(.*)-(\d+)$/", "$1", "product name with color-0250")
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use `strrpos()`:

```
$str = 'product name with color-0250';
$pos = strrpos($str, '-');       
echo substr($str, 0, $pos); //Returns: product name with color
```

Comment: Better use `strrpos`, because it might be not the only dash in the string.

Answer (score 1):

use `explode()` option.

```
$test = 'product name with color-0250';
$hi = explode('-',$test);
var_dump($hi[0]); //will give 'product name with color'
```